# asp.net GridView not showing data from Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I have two GridViews, the first works fine as I defined the datasource when I dropped it onto the asp page via visual studio and I specified the table to use.

The other GridView (dgvParams below) has just been dropped onto the asp page and I want to use it at run time:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports myDataBase

Partial Class TestWeb
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim data As New cDatabase

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        dgvParams = New GridView

        LoadParamsGrid()
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadParamsGrid()


        ' Create the dataset
        Dim strCon As String = data.DBConn.ConnectionString
        Dim strSQL As String = "dbo.GetParameters"
        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon)
        Dim table As New DataTable

        Try
            dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' try again
            dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        End Try

        dgvParams.DataSource = table
        dgvParams.DataBind()


    End Sub

End Class
```

When I step through the code I can see row and column counts are as expected and call "dgvParams.DataSource = table".

I think I am missing another step somewhere so that I can physically see the data on the GridView?  Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Are you missing a DataBind?

dgvParams.DataSource.DataBind after setting the DataSource

Comment: I tried that but still I get no data in the GridView.  I updated my sourcecode above to reflect it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed fro using a table to a dataset and it just "worked"... although not right away!  Not sure really what made this work but this is what I am using now:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet

Try
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
Catch ex As Exception
    ' try again
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
End Try

dgvParams.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
dgvParams.DataBind()
```

Comment: hi
why do you try "dataAdapter.Fill(ds)" in the cath block again?

Answer (score 1):

Is the AutoGenerateColumns property on dgvParams set to True or are the columns already explicitly defined?

Comment: I tried both methods and they both gave no results.  Then suddenly, it started to work as expected! very odd.  I did change from using a table to dataset as a test which may have done something different! Although it didnt when I tried and gave the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
dgvParams = new GridView();
```

But I don't see where you add it to the web page so you can see it.  Any dynamically created controls must be added to the control collection of the page or another control like:

```
panel.Controls.Add(dgvParams);
```

Where panel would be an  that is used to mark where you want to place the gridview in the page.  Or, embed the  in the page, give it the dgvParams ID, and bind to that instead.

Or, if you have the dgvParams already in the page as an , remove the dgvParams = new GridView() statement.

Also, if you bind to a dataset, you need to set DataMember to the data table name so it knows which table to bind to.

HTH.